# Fractional type with Maybe

Tags: haskell

What is wrong with the type of ( x / y ) ?

```
my :: (Integral a, Fractional b) =>  a -> a -> Maybe b            
my x y
 | y == 0 = Nothing
 | otherwise = Just ( x / y )
```

Comment: the division operator `/` is not implemented for `Integral` or `Num`, while you are using it on an `Integral`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [**`(/) :: Fractional a => a -> a -> a`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.16.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:-47-) requires that the two operands and the return type are all the same. This thus means that your `my` should be written as:

```
my :: (Eq a, Fractional a) => a -> a -> Maybe a
my _ 0 = Nothing
my x y = Just (x / y)
```

Another option is to work with [**`(%) :: Integral a => a -> a -> Ratio a`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.16.0.0/docs/Data-Ratio.html#v:-37-) and [**`fromRational :: Fractional a => Rational -> a`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.16.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:fromRational):

```
import Data.Ratio((%))

my :: (Integral a, Fractional b) => a -> a -> Maybe b
my _ 0 = Nothing
my x y = Just (fromRational (fromIntegral x % fromIntegral y))
```